# Where is firefox's `Restore Session` page's XUL?

Tags: firefox, xul

Like there's [firefox interface's XUL `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`](https://superuser.com/a/503823/120159),

What similarly is the XUL for editing the "Restore Session" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Restore Session" page is accessible via:

- `chrome://browser/content/aboutSessionRestore.xhtml`
- `about:sessionrestore`

The actual file itself lives at the following path in the Gecko repo:

- [`browser/components/sessionstore/content/aboutSessionRestore.xhtml`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/sessionstore/content/aboutSessionRestore.xhtml)